# What is the difference between polonium-210 in my school lab and polonium-210 used to kill Alexander Litvinenko?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Polonium-210 was used to murder Alexander Litvinenko in London in 2006. That dose was estimated to cost $8m and had to be created in a nuclear reactor. A tiny dose of it was incredibly deadly.

I'm a high school physics teacher and we use polonium-210 as an example of an alpha source in class. It costs a couple of hundred dollars and is safe enough for the classroom.

What is the difference?

Comment: not ingesting it, for one

Comment: What would you think it may be? What is the difference between the cyanide in apple seeds which is pretty safe and the one used to kill people in the detective movies? (and real life, unfortunately).

Comment: "The poison is in the dose", and the needle source you can get for classroom use have nano-curie activities. The stuff used on Litvinenko would have been upwards of millicuries (I've never worked out the necessary level, but the KGB (whatever they are calling themselves these days) would have been thorough). What's six orders of magnitude between freinds?

Comment: @Christoph Well obviously, but that can be said for most things we have in our science labs

Comment: Half life of $^{210}Po$ is less than 139 days.  Are you sure that's really what you have?  $^{209}Po$ also is an alpha source, and it has a half-life greater than 100 years.   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_polonium)

Comment: And @jameslarge - that is the real physics answer. Different isotopes have different properties.

Comment: @jameslarge You can get needle source that are actually $^{210}\mathrm{Pb}$ sources. That keeps the polonium daughter refreshed with the lead's 20 year half-life. That way you get the high-energy alpha line and a decent half-life at the cost of also having the two beta lines from the lead and bismuth.

Comment: @dmckee, I should have realized that they'd do something like that.  I worked for ten years for a medical device manufacturer, and I am familiar with where the Nuclear Medicine department in a hospital gets its steady supply of $^{99m}Tc$ (half-life, 6 hours).

Comment: @jameslarge It's definitely 210. The catalogues actually recommend replacing it every few months due to the short half life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantity and location. Yes, you can buy an 0.1 $\mu$Ci source for about [\$150](https://www.flinnsci.com/alpha-source-polonium-210/ap8794/). But a lethal dose is 3,500 $\mu$Ci,
 according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Alexander_Litvinenko#Polonium-210). And since polonium is an alpha emitter, and alpha particles can be stopped by paper (or skin), the polonium needs to be ingested in order for the alpha particles to destroy the more vulnerable cells inside the body.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this, though my follow-up questions would be:
1) What else, apart from polonium-210 (and its daughter nuclei), is contained in my lab samples?
2) Where are the school lab samples being created? Are they also coming from nuclear reactors?

Comment: And if one gathers samples from 35000 schools, would they then have a lethal dose? There seem to be few restrictions (in the US at least).

Comment: 1) I can't know the answer; what do the labels on the samples say? 2) According to Wikipedia above, only Russia is producing new Po-210; the stuff you've got is either from a stockpile or from there. 3) Yes. I recall a story of someone buying up a very large number of smoke detectors (which have the alpha emitter americium inside) and ruffling a lot of feathers at the US NRC, but a brief Google search didn't yield any confirmation.

Comment: You might be interested in the amazing story David Hahn, https://harpers.org/archive/1998/11/the-radioactive-boy-scout/ and https://www.amazon.com/Radioactive-Boy-Scout-Frightening-Homemade/dp/0812966600 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hahn